# URL rewriting in asp

Tags: asp-classic

Is it possible to rewrite the URL of a web (Including Domain of the web) to other domain.
eg

http://www.abc.com.au/article.asp?a=12&z=23

to

http://www.xyz.com.au/artcle.asp  or http://www.xyz.com.au/article.asp?a=12&z=23

if possible, any help or example...

Thankyou.

Comment: Are you looking to redirect the user to another site (easy to do), or are you basically trying to impersonate the other site?

Comment: thanks for reply. Infact, I have two hosted websites eg abc.com and xyz.com.

abc.com displays only headlines and xyz.com displays full article. when user clicks on the headline on abc.com it redirects to xyz.com/article.asp...... I need to write xyz.com to abc.com.... Is it possible.. i am not finding any answer..

Comment: Why don't you just have the links point to xyz.com to begin with? Even if you put in a redirect, web browsers might not take it for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You can use asp to redirect, using http 301 or javascript.

```
<%@language=VBScript %>
<%
Response.Status="301 Moved Permanently"
Response.AddHeader "Location", "/new-page.asp"
%>
```

Or you can just set all `<a>` tags to xyz.com/article.asp

```
'page on abc.com
<a href="xyz.com/article.asp">
```